# didSelectRowAt not called in custom UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After some refactoring I decided to create a custom tableview that looks a bit like:

```
class BaseTable: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var rowsInSection: Int { return  0}

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rowsInSection
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        return cell
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "headerCell")!
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
```

And then I subclass it like this:

```
class CustomTable: BaseTable{
    override var rowsInSection: Int {return payArray.count }
}
```

This works fine, however I've noticed none of the subclassed didSelectRowAt are being called??? Can anyone help?

Comment: are you sure that the tableView data source and delegate are connected to the viewController?

Comment: I've set the delegate and data source in the base table class.

Comment: New development...I'm pretty sure this is something to do with gesture recogniser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should follow this things:

1. You should split up logic from `initWithCoder:` to external method such as and call it in `initWithFrame:`, because different approaches called different `init` methods. Such as

`func setUpTableView() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
        self.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}`

2. For clarity in your code, you **should** explicitly call `super` method from child class methods
3. Otherwise, I *strongly* recommend you not to use this approach, better use standard `UITableView` in controller, and different classes, that implements protocols alongside with custom `UITableViewCell`'s

Comment: Thanks...I didnt know what super did, but I've looked it up and now I did. That's much clearer. Unfortunately I'm reluctant to go back to standard UITableViews in the controller because I've spent so long refactoring like this :(

Comment: I'm glad that you are doing things well. Otherwise, do not forget to mark question as resolved if community helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design. The reason there are delegate and data source protocols for `UITableView`s is because view objects should be reusable. You're making your `BaseTable` class to function as a controller as well as a view.

To answer your question, are you sure it's not being called? You only have `deselectRow(at:animated:)` calling from `tableView(didSelectRowAt:)`

Comment: Thats a shame. I'm fairly new and thought this was a much better way of implementing tables. Its taken me all week to refactor them like this. I have quite a lot of tableviews inside viewcontrollers, Refactoring it like this really reduces my code. But thanks for the feedback. And yes, I'm sure it wasn't being called. Above was just an example. I have tried adding print("say something") to the didSelectRowAt and nothing...